# curl command BashOpertor in Cloud Composer

Tags: bash, curl, google-cloud-composer

I am following the tutorial mentioned in this link - [download_rocket_launches.py](https://github.com/BasPH/data-pipelines-with-apache-airflow/blob/master/chapter02/dags/download_rocket_launches.py) . As I am running this in Cloud Composer, I want to put in the native path i.e. /home/airflow/gcs/dags but it's failing with error path not found.

What path can I give for this command to work? Here is the task I am trying to execute -

```
download_launches = BashOperator(
    task_id="download_launches",
    bash_command="curl -o /tmp/launches.json -L 'https://ll.thespacedevs.com/2.0.0/launch/upcoming'",  # noqa: E501
    dag=dag,
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked on my end:

```py
import json
import pathlib

import airflow.utils.dates
import requests
import requests.exceptions as requests_exceptions
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="download_rocket_launches",
    description="Download rocket pictures of recently launched rockets.",
    start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(14),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
)

download_launches = BashOperator(
    task_id="download_launches",
    bash_command="curl -o  /home/airflow/gcs/data/launches.json -L 'https://ll.thespacedevs.com/2.0.0/launch/upcoming' ",  # put space in between single quote and double quote 
    dag=dag,
)


download_launches
```

Output:

[image]

The key was to put space between single quote `'` and double quote `"` towards the end of your bash command.

Also, it is recommended to use the [`Data`](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#folders_in_the_bucket) folder when it comes to mapping out your output file as stated in the GCP documentation:

> gs://bucket-name/data /home/airflow/gcs/data: Stores the data that tasks produce and use. This folder is mounted on all worker nodes.

Comment: Thanks Angela. I did run as you specified. The dag was successful but there was no output in the folder.

Comment: Did you map the output to `/home/airflow/gcs/data/` instead of `/home/airflow/gcs/dags`?

Comment: Thanks, Just realized it went to the root folder. It's working now. Am just surprised why it doesn't recognize sub folders under dags folder.